# How to make a plot over some external figure?

Tags: plotting, syntax

Consider the following figure:

[image]

I would like to plot a test function

```
func[ma_]=1000*ma^5
```

over it. Is it possible somehow to do?

Comment: When you say `figure`, you mean this is an image of a plot only available as an image file?

Comment: @Syed : yes, that's it.

Comment: My answer below works for raster images. But since you probably got the image from a PDF, you could also extract a vector graphics, and then overlay your plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) and [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) to position the image behind the plot, but some calibration is needed to get correct coordinates.

First, calibrate the image by determining the location of the bottom-left and top-right corners of the plot.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUBAY.png", "Image", 
 ImageResolution -> 72];

imageData = ImageData[img, DataReversed -> True];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Raster[imageData, {{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[img]}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 500], {{bottomLeft, {0, 0}}}, {{topRight, {300, 
    300}}}, {{bottomLeft, {0, 0}}, Locator}, {{topRight, {300, 300}}, 
  Locator}]
```

[image: Locator]

Then assign the corresponding $x$ and $y$ range*, and use this data to calculate the correct aspect ratio and image scaling.

```
bottomLeft = {182, 151};
topRight = {1687, 966};

{xRange, yRange} = {{0, 3}, {-3, 7}};

aspectRatio = 1/Divide @@ (topRight - bottomLeft);
scaling = Abs[Subtract @@ xRange]*
   First@ImageDimensions[img]/First@(topRight - bottomLeft);
```

Finally, use `Plot`* to draw your function. Make sure the axes are properly aligned, then use `Frame -> False` and remove `SetAlphaChannel` to get the final image.

```
func[ma_] := 1000 * ma^5;

Plot[Log10[func[ma]], {ma, xRange[[1]], 
  xRange[[2]]}, {PlotRange -> {xRange, yRange}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
  Prolog -> {Inset[
     SetAlphaChannel[img, .3], {xRange[[1]], yRange[[1]]}, bottomLeft,
      scaling]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -3}, AspectRatio -> aspectRatio, 
  Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> True, ImagePadding -> 50, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, Frame -> True}]
```

[image]

---

* Due to plot coordinate system, it is more convenient to use `Plot[Log10[ ...]]` instead of `LogPlot[]`.